# Computer with Ubuntu won't shut down with USB peripherals plugged in

Tags: 14.04, usb

I have quite low-quality USB 2.0 hub with additional power supply which I use to plug in peripherals like keyboard and laptop cooler. When I click on Ubuntu top bar and choose "Shut Down..." option everything but wallpaper disappears, but computer won't turn off. If I plug out all peripherals computer sometimes will not turn off anyway - but it's not always the rule.
I remember I had similar issues when using Windows 8.1, but somehow resolved it playing with Power Options - and since then turning off works fine with W8.1. Can I repair it in Ubuntu?
Also:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

with peripherals plugged in makes everything but terminal and wallpaper invisible and system is stuck without any message.

Comment: try `sudo  shutdown -P now`

Comment: @Serg stuck as well :(